# Reuse SpecFlow steps in another project in the same solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, specflow

What is the best way to reuse SpecFlow Given/When/Then steps? I figured out three ways with all specific advantages and drawbacks, but I am not convinced this is the best way.

I have two projects in one solution
ProjectA:

```
[Binding]
public class BookSteps : StepsBase
{
    [Given(@"the following books:")]
    public void GivenTheFollowingBooks(Table table)
    { 
        // ...
    }
}
```

1. I can just inherit my steps like this:

`ProjectB:`

```
[Binding]
public class BookStepsReference : ProjectA.BookSteps { }
```

This works and requires the least work. Unfortunately it breaks the intellisense of the feature files: The steps stay purple in the ProjectB feature files.

2. I can inherit and create a method with the same signature:

`ProjectB:`

```
[Binding]
public class BookStepsReference : ProjectA.BookSteps 
{ 
    [Given(@"the following books:")]
    public void GivenTheFollowingBooksReference(Table table)
    { 
        base.GivenTheFollowingBooks(table);
    }
}
```

This breaks when I try to run the test because the auto-generated feature steps sees two methods with a Given attribute "the following books:" and throws an ambiguous reference exception.

3. I make a private object that references the binding steps from the project A:

`ProjectB:`

```
[Binding]
public class BookStepsReference
{ 
    private ProjectA.BookSteps _bookSteps = new ProjectA.BookSteps();

    [Given(@"the following books:")]
    public void GivenTheFollowingBooks(Table table)
    { 
        _bookSteps.GivenTheFollowingBooks(table);
    }
}
```

This works and also applies the correct intellisense on the Feature File steps. But when I want to debug my steps, I get an external COM exception on the initializing of the _baseSteps object, probably caused by the SpecFlow library that sees a double Binding attribute.

The last option is the way I am working right now, but I'd like to know if others have created a better way to reuse steps from other projects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The supported way is to add a reference to the project which has the steps you want to reuse into the project you want to use then in and then [define an external step assembly](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Use-Bindings-from-External-Assemblies) in the config like this:

```
<specFlow>
   <stepAssemblies>
     <stepAssembly assembly="MyAssembly.Name" />
   </stepAssemblies>
</specFlow>
```

If you need to only reuse some steps then you might need to extract those steps into a separate library first.

Comment: Ah, forgot about that. It seems I can just use the same setup as I have now and only have to enter the above lines in my configuration.

Answer (score 3):

When you add stepAssembly (see below) to config then intellisence can`t see steps from stepAssembly. 
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167820/specflow-error-force-regenerate-steps-possible/21536348#21536348?newreg=774efcea65f74b0f9e788d1adbbbce45) how delete specFlow cache and allow this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Specflow 3, this is the updated link
https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Use-Bindings-from-External-Assemblies.html

**specflow.json** example:

```
{
  "stepAssemblies": [
    {
      "assembly": "MySharedBindings"
    }
  ]
}
```

**app.config** example:

```
<specFlow>
  <stepAssemblies>
    <stepAssembly assembly="MySharedBindings" />
  </stepAssemblies>
</specFlow>
```