# SpecFlow step bindings very flaky when using an external assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2015, specflow

As the title says, I have step bindings in an external assembly. I have brought them into the project using:

```
  <specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="xUnit" />
    <plugins>
      <add name="SpecFlow.xUnitAdapter" type="Runtime" />
    </plugins>
    <stepAssemblies>
      <stepAssembly assembly="MyOtherProject.StepBindings" />
    </stepAssemblies>
  </specFlow>
```

While the `.feature` file runs and the tests pass just fine, the steps all appear unbound (purple) in the Visual Studio editor and hitting `F12` provides a dialog with suggested code.

What do I need to do to get bound step highlights?

This post does not help: [Specflow Binding from External Assembly always purple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528153/specflow-binding-from-external-assembly-always-purple)

I have cleared the `%TEMP%\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions` to no avail.

Comment: Seems like know issues https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/220, https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/838, https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/648, https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/502 and also seems like they don't want to invest much time on it

Comment: The plugin is open source. I was planning to take a look at the repo, but I don't have much experience writing VS plugins. Was hoping this post might throw the net in the direction of someone who does/is/would.

Comment: @tarun-lalwani Would you like to post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of issues listed for the same

https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/220

https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/838

https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/648

https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/502

And seems like no one is right now interested to fix this.