# Specflow not recognizing steps

Tags: c#, .net, specflow

I have a specflow Feature file with the following `When`

```
When Request for servername 'someurl.com/szhm04c4.xml' is processed
```

When I press `F12` Visual Studio tells me that I can copy the following Step-Definition:

```
[When(@"Request for servername '(.*)' is processed")]
public void WhenRequestForServernameIsProcessed(string p0)
{
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}
```

I paste this to my step-file which inherits from `Steps` and implement it

```
public void WhenRequestForServernameIsProcessed(string servername)
{
    var httpRequest = this.Bootstrapper.GetFake<IHttpRequest>();
    A.CallTo(() => httpRequest.Path).Returns(servername);

    var httpContext = this.Bootstrapper.Get<IHttpContext>();

    this.Bootstrapper.Get<IHostRequest>().Process(httpContext);
}
```

When I execute the test, it fials and I get following error message:

> TechTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException Test pending: No matching step
>   definition found for one or more steps. using System; using
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow;
>
> namespace MyNamespace {
>       [Binding]
>       public class StepDefinitions
>       {
>           [When(@"Request for servername '(.*)' is processed")] public void WhenRequestForServernameIsProcessed(string p0) {
>       ScenarioContext.Current.Pending(); }
>       } }

Why is that? I did define this step...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your step in code have the `When` attribute on it?

Comment: Does your binding class have the [Binding] Attribute on it?

Comment: Thank you! The [Binding] Attribute was missing, you can add this as answer if you want then i'm gonna mark is as solved :-)

Comment: Related post - [Specflow error: Force regenerate steps possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17167820/465053)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to put the [Binding] Attribute to the class, so that SpecFlow can find your steps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

- The step does exist (search for the step's description in the source files)
- The step corresponds to a public method in a public class decorated with [Binding]
- The parameters of the step's description, usage in feature, supporting C# function line up.
- The steps attribute is ONE string. You can't concatenate e.g. a prefix or suffix.

If the test is in a separate assembly:

- It has to be declared in a file at the root of that assembly (Specflow limitation).
- That assembly has to be referenced in a  tag of the feature file's assembly (see the doc).

Not that you cannot have multiple [Binding] classes with the same name (even if a different namespace) or specflow will be confused and may not find your steps.